# Enforce two factor authentication in google compute engine projects

Tags: google-compute-engine

I use google compute engine in an organisation of ~100 people. How do I make sure that all the accounts I add to a compute engine project have two factor auth enabled?

I searched google documentation for `(enforce|ensure|mandatory) two factor (gcloud|gce|google cloud)` but didn't find anything that answered my question.

Comment: Stackoverflow was faster: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158379/enforce-two-factor-authentication-in-google-compute-engine-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Identity is an Identity as a service solution that allows Cloud administrators the ability to manage users from the Google Admin Console.

This makes it easier to manage users within an organisation, as settings can be configured for large numbers of users from a single place (i.e. the Google Admin Console).

Amongst other things, It also provides administrators with the ability to manage account security, including an the option to apply 2-factor authentication to users.

Before any change is made, as 2-Step verification will be different for each user, and because a step in the process will inevitably involves some user manual enrolment, it's a good idea for users to be notified of the new security process and provided with instructions before it's implemented.

Then 2-factor verification can be achieved by following these steps.

1. If 2 step-verification is mandatory, the admin must switch to the administrator account, and Enable 2-Step Verification for the domain in the Google Admin console. See [here](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/184711) for how to enable 2-Step Verification for your account.
2. The users must enrol in 2-Step Verification and selects the method for receiving their verification code on their mobile phone: Google prompt, the Authenticator app, text message or phone call, Security Key or printable backup codes. The instruction of how to do this are [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?visit_id=1-636435045103056073-219194462&rd=1)
3. The next time the user signs in to their managed Google account on a new browser or device, they enter their username and password as usual. They're then prompted with a second page to enter a verification code.
4. Depending on how they opted to receive their code, the user gets their time-based, one-time code from the Google Authenticator app on their smartphone or via text message or phone call. They then enter the code to successfully sign in.